# Android: Getting this error during generate sign apk

Tags: android, gradle, apk, sign

I am getting this error during generate sign APK. please help me.

see this errors

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
    Warning:com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl: can't find referenced method 'long getContentLengthLong()' in program class com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl
    Warning:com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl: can't find referenced method 'long getHeaderFieldLong(java.lang.String,long)' in program class com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl
    Warning:com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.JavaApiConverter$CacheHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced method 'long getContentLengthLong()' in program class com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.JavaApiConverter$CacheHttpURLConnection
    Warning:com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.JavaApiConverter$CacheHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced method 'long getHeaderFieldLong(java.lang.String,long)' in program class com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.JavaApiConverter$CacheHttpURLConnection
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced field 'com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl FORCE_CACHE' in program class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced method 'com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder cacheControl(com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl)' in program class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
    Warning:okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
    Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
    Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
    Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
    Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
    Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
    Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
    Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
    Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
    Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
    Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
    Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
    Warning:there were 21 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
    Warning:there were 6 unresolved references to program class members.
    Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
    > Job failed, see logs for details
    Information:BUILD FAILED
    Information:Total time: 30.672 secs
    Information:1 error
    Information:23 warnings
    Information:See complete output in console
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this

If you are using ProGuard you might need to add the following option:

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
```

Check the [docs](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: "sign apk generate but not run in mobile". Then when this error is being thrown.

Comment: Warning:okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
i am add -dontwarn okio.** in proguard all warning and errors will be gone and also sign apk is generated but not run in mobile...just open app and shut down without any crash.

Comment: try adding this line as well, -dontwarn okio.**, check https://github.com/square/okio/issues/60

Comment: i am adding -dontwarn okio.** and -dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.** in proguard all warning and errors will be gone and also sign apk is generated but not run in mobile...just open app and shut down without any crash. even i am disabled instant run

Comment: strangem, there seems some other issue or I am not getting it.